# Access Post and Get variables in a server control class

Tags: asp.net

I need to access post and get variables inside a server control class, there is no access to Request object in server control class...

Comment: try using the FQN - `HttpContext.Current.Request`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get access to the request through the context object.

e.g.

```
this.Context.Request
```